# <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/admin.css' %}"> Not working

Tags: html, css, django

When I make the website outside of Django it works perfectly fine. However, when I integrate everything in and put the CSS file in static files, it fails to load. The JavaScript file in the same folder loads perfectly fine. The files being used are: `base.html`, `adminDash.html`, `admin.js`, `main.css`, and `admin.css`. The `admin.css` file is the one specific to `adminDash.html` and is the one failing to load. Attached are images of all files, what the site should look like, and what it currently looks like.

**`admin.js`**

[image]

**`main.css`**

[image]

**`admin.css`**

[image]

**`adminDash.html`**

[image]

**`base.html`**

[image]

**What it looks like outside Django:**

[image]

**What it looks like inside Django:**

[image]

I have tried running it outside of the Django project, changing the file location, getting some friends to have a go at it, and getting `chatGPT` to try rewriting it.

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Answer (score 0):

In **`settings.py`** include your static file details:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
STATICFILES_DIRS=[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]`
```

Then run collect the static file.

```bash
➜ python manage.py collectstatic
```

Then load the below statement in **`base.html`** file:

```
{% load static %}
```

Hope this will help